# Register Windows Phone 8.1 App as Auto Photo Uploader

Tags: windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, photo, background-task

For Windows Phone 8 Apps it is possible to [register themselves as an Auto-upload app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj571205(v=vs.105).aspx) for photos that have been taken by the camera.

Is there an equivalent in the Windows Phone 8.1 (RT) APIs?
I have not found anything that would let me start an automatic background upload of photos like OneDrive for example does.

This was definately possible at Windows Phone 8!

Hope they didn't drop it...

Comment: It was on Silverlight. Probably just isn't yet supported on WP 8.1 WinRT.